# How to Execute a Multi-Line PowerShell Script Using Java

Tags: java, powershell, format, runtime

I'm am trying to launch a PowerShell script from Java using Runtime. Below is the code I have:

```
String command = ("powershell.exe Get-Process");
String line;

Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();

BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));

while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
stdout.close();
```

However, instead of "Get-Process," I'd need to execute the following (the following is a snippet, but it shows my point). I tried just copying it without any formatting into the String, but due to the occurrence of many quotation marks in the PowerShell code, it throws errors.

```
...
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[string]$Server,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
[string]$Site,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]
[string]$Path,
...
```

How would I execute this multi-line script, because when I try to replace the "Get-Process" with the above code, it throws a bunch of errors, but when i execute my script manually through CMD, it's fine. I tried formatting it like the following, but to no avail:

```
   ...
    param (
    " +
    "    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]\n" +
    "    [string]$Server,\n" +
    "    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]\n" +
    "    [string]$Site,\n" +
    "    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]\n" +
    "    [string]$Path,
    ...
```

This gives me the error:

```
At line:1 char:258
+ ... =$False,Position=4)] [string]$Filename ) $appVer = '1.3.1' if (!$Serv...
+ ~~ Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement. At line:1 char:2517
+ ... eUrl = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://$Server, $file.L
```

So, can anyone help me correctly execute a multi-line PowerShell script from Java using Runtime?

Comment: What errors are thrown when you update your script?

Comment: It isn't a Java Exception, but error from PowerShell caught through ErrorStream:                                                                                          At line:1 char:258
+ ... =$False,Position=4)] [string]$Filename ) $appVer = '1.3.1' if (!$Serv ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:2517
+ ... eUrl = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://$Server, $file.L ...

Comment: However, these errors only show up when I run the script using this method. Running it through PowerShell manually yields no errors.

Comment: Would it be possible to separate each line using semi-colons?

Comment: Is it not possible to store the multiple lines externally in a script or plain text file? Have you tried `powershell.exe -Command {...}` where `...` is the multiline string variable?